# when using fopen with thread the virtual memory will increase

Tags: linux, libc

on my linux(CentOS dis). when I create a POSIX thread by pthread,and pass a callback fucntion(thread function),in that function,I use FILE* fp = fopen(); will make the per thread's virtual memory increase to 80MB,yes,when I create 4 threads,the process's vm allocated about 320MB, I don't known what happened is it??,

Comment: You might use `strace` or `ltrace` to find out, or dive into [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html) source code... Why does it matters to you?

Comment: thanks for reply,I just want to known why. :)